# How do you allow users of a domain group to connect/use a svrconn channel in client mode?

Tags: ibm-mq

What I am trying to do is to allow all users of a domain group to use a `SVRCONN` channel, I tried to apply a `CHLAUTH` rule on the domain group so that all users could access the channel but it didn't work.

Below is the `CHLAUTH` set:

> ```
> dis chlauth(c.mqtest.usr)
>     13 : dis chlauth(c.mqtest.usr) AMQ8878I: Display channel authentication record details.    CHLAUTH(C.MQTEST.USR)             
> TYPE(USERMAP)    DESCR( )                                CUSTOM( )   
> ADDRESS(40.1.62.159)                    CLNTUSER(MQ_Support@am)   
> MCAUSER(mq_pocmq9w02@am)                USERSRC(MAP)   
> CHCKCLNT(ASQMGR)                        ALTDATE(2019-05-09)   
> ALTTIME(09.05.34)
> ```

I tried to issue a MFT command:

> ```
> fteCreateTransfer -p DLYMQMGR -sa D_MQTEST_L -sm DLYMCTEST -da
> D_MQTEST_L -dm DLYMCTEST -td
> E:\home\mqm\monitors\RUN_FIFO_SCANNER_DEV.xml 5655-MFT, 5724-H72
> Copyright IBM Corp.  2008, 2017.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED BFGPR0127W: No
> credentials file has been specified to connect to WebSphere MQ.
> Therefore, the assumption is that WebSphere MQ authentication has been
> disabled.
>
> BFGCL0734E:  An attempt to connect to queue manager DLYMQMGR has been
> rejected because of invalid authentication details. If this queue
> manager has authentication enabled, user ID and password details must
> be supplied.
> ```

While at the queue manager end I could see my id getting blocked, is there any possible way this could be fixed?

> ```
> AMQ9777E: Channel was blocked
>
> EXPLANATION: The inbound channel 'C.MQTEST.USR' was blocked from
> address 'MQTEST (40.1.62.159)' because the active values of the
> channel matched a record configured with USERSRC(NOACCESS). The active
> values of the channel were 'CLNTUSER(c275607)
> ```

Comment: `CHLAUTH` map users (as the parameter indicates [`CLNTUSER` = Client ***USER***]) not groups.  If `MQ_Support@am` is a group not a user this rule would never work.  What version of MQ is the queue manager and the MFT agents?  If the queue manager is at a supported version (v8.0 or later) then you could setup `CONNAUTH` and if the MFT agents are at a sufficient version they can pass a username and password for MQ to authenticate, at that point you can provide OAM at the domain group level rather than MAP them to a specific `MCAUSER`.

Comment: Another option, you are passing a cert from the client, if the clients have certs that can be trusted, you could ensure they have certs that match a `SSLPEER` value and use a `CHLAUTH TYPE(SSLPEERMAP)` rule instead to match on the cert's `DN` value and map to a specific `MCAUSER`.

Comment: Thanks JoshMc for your inputs, you just cleared my head where I was going wrong.I will try to authenticate the client by passing user ID and password. I will post in here with the results.